# Angular 4 adding a component with unclosed element

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm developing a project using Angular 4
my app component:

```
<app-header></app-header>
<app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
<div class="content-wrapper">
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

when ever i put div of content-wrapper and in app sidebar html and close it at the begining of the footer , the app keeps loading, also this happens when it's a div without a class or any other element

Comment: You could have an `<app-header-and-footer>` component with an `<ng-content>` element to get the same effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template of a component needs to be valid HTML, therefore only having the opening or only the closing element in a template is not supported.

You could have an `<app-header-and-footer>` component with an `<ng-content>` element to get the same effect.

```
<app-header-and-footer></app-header-and-footer>
  <app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
  <div class="content-wrapper">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
</app-header-and-footer>
```

```
@Component({
   selector: 'app-header-and-footer',
   template: '<ng-content></ng-content>'
})
export class AppHeaderAndFooter{}
```